# screwed up 16.04 to 18.04 install, black screen

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

i used an install guide i cannot find now because it was on the computer running linux before it crashed.  anyway it had me do it through terminal.  it downloaded and installed very quickly and then said "done but some packages could not install" or something like that.

i restarted and it was the new home screen wallpaper with 0 icons.  i tried a couple of terminal requests from google recommendations but nothing worked, so i booted into safe mode and said "repair packages."  at that point it said it would update me to 18.04 and i said yes.  it appeared to be working and was gradually increasing % completion until it got stuck on something that said

"created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/motd-news-timer -> /lib/systemd/sy... (my picture cut off)

it was stuck for several hours before i decided it was locked and saw a guide to resume a stuck install to reboot and go to terminal and initiate some commands.  well, it never got to a screen i could work on.  the screen just kept going on and off, on and off, on and off (black off and black screen on).  i went back into safe mode, that worked, tried to repair and immediately it said done!  when i restarted it said "welcome to ubuntu 17.10" and then went back to the screen on/off loop. I tried boot mode run in failsafe graphic mode and it says no screen found and won't boot.

i have no idea what i've done but obviously something incorrect.  thanks for your suggestions and help to get me back on track.